# How do I exclude certain strings when using grepl?

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Food = c("Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Donut", "Eclair", "Flour"),
  Ingredient = c("salt", "sodium chloride", "salt replacer", "unsalted", "veg salt", "vegetable salt")
)
```

I want to use grepl to create a variable that shows TRUE when "salt" or "sodium chloride" are present but FALSE for other values "salt replacer", "unsalted", veg salt", "vegetable salt".

The output should be a dataframe that looks like this:

| Food | Ingredient | Salt_Present |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | salt | TRUE |
| Banana | sodium chloride | TRUE |
| Carrot | salt replacer | FALSE |
| Donut | unsalted | FALSE |
| Eclair | veg salt | FALSE |
| Flour | vegetable salt | FALSE |

I am having difficulty writing the regex to achieve this.

**How can I write a regex that will return true for Apple and Banana, but false for the other cases in the data?**

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/XTdXM6/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Food = c("Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Donut", "Eclair", "Flour"),
  Ingredient = c("salt", "sodium chloride", "salt replacer", "unsalted", "veg salt", "vegetable salt")
)

df %>% mutate(
  Salt_Present = grepl("^salt$|^sodium chloride$",Ingredient)
)
```

`^` and `$` ensure that there are no partial matches.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I suggest to use an `if_else` statement with the `%in%` operator:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Salt_present = if_else(Ingredient %in% c("salt", "sodium chloride"), TRUE, FALSE))

    Food      Ingredient Salt_present
1  Apple            salt         TRUE
2 Banana sodium chloride         TRUE
3 Carrot   salt replacer        FALSE
4  Donut        unsalted        FALSE
5 Eclair        veg salt        FALSE
6  Flour  vegetable salt        FALSE
```

or much better, thanks to @user2554330
just use the expression `Ingredient %in% c("salt", "sodium chloride")`

Comment: It's simpler to skip the `if_else` call, and just use the expression `Ingredient %in% c("salt", "sodium chloride")` directly.

Comment: Much better!!!. Thanks! I have added your input!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  Food = c("Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Donut", "Eclair", "Flour"),
  Ingredient = c("salt", "sodium chloride", "salt replacer", "unsalted", "veg salt", "vegetable salt")
)


print(df)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Salt_Present = case_when(
    Ingredient %in% c("salt", "sodium chloride") ~ TRUE,
    TRUE ~ FALSE
  ))
 print(df)
Food      Ingredient Salt_Present
1  Apple            salt         TRUE
2 Banana sodium chloride         TRUE
3 Carrot   salt replacer        FALSE
4  Donut        unsalted        FALSE
5 Eclair        veg salt        FALSE
6  Flour  vegetable salt        FALSE
```

Comment: The double backslash in `\\b` is correct for the word boundary. A single backslash matches the literal `\b`. The other backslashes are dubious though,.